# Why Zend Framework 2.0 is less than 1.2?

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

I downloaded the new version of Zend Framework 2.0 and noticed that it has less features than the version 1.2, both in framework folder and externals.
What is the reason? Does Zend have a new policy to you include some features as extensions or this is related to become more lightweight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zend_Service(S) now have each one his own repository with his own live cycle, by this way that services can be adapted soon to the vendor API changes.

Zend_Date, Zend_Currency, ... and other locale components have been replaced by PHP 5.3 API (DateTime, NumberFormat, etc) there is a new i18N component for translates.

Other components was not in use, and others are not enough stable for to go with the main distro.

Here you have the full list of repositories for the main distro and other components https://github.com/zendframework/

Answer (score 0):

In zf2.0 only standard components are included, the components that are essential for the application development. The remaining components can be included on-demand.

You can read more about this in http://framework.zend.com/downloads/

The reasons for making this such lightweight is explained by  Matthew Weier O'Phinney http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Zend+Framework+2.0+Requirements